# Firebase function: Callable request verification passed

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have defined a firebase function like this:

```
exports.getTestResults = functions.region("europe-west3").https.onCall((data, context) => {
    return {
        test: 'Test 123'
    }
})
```

If I call this function as follows

```
var getTestResults = firebase.app().functions('europe-west3').httpsCallable('getTestResults');
getTestResults({ }).then(response => {
    console.log(response);
}).catch(ex => {
    console.log('EXC: ' + ex);
})
```

I get this error/warning/whatever in the firebase function log

```
Callable request verification passed {"verifications":{"app":"MISSING","auth":"VALID"}}
```

What is the cause of this?

Comment: Did you enable [App Check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/web?hl=el_GR&skip_cache=false#metrics-functions) in your web app?

Comment: No, I didnt. Thank you for your advice!

Comment: Was the solution enable the [AppCheck](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/web?hl=el_GR&skip_cache=false#metrics-functions) ?

Comment: This is definitely an App Check problem. For anyone facing this issue, check out https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/web/debug-provider and follow the instructions to register App Check on localhost or a CI environment.

Comment: None of these answers provide a solution. They only help identify the problem, which we've already done.

Comment: With AppCheck, I was able to get "app": "VALID". But how to get "auth":"VALID"? For me, it is still as "MISSING"

Comment: @Botirkhuja it will get automatically valid if the user/client is authenticated when sending the request. When the call is coming from unauthenticated users it shows up as "MISSING".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not using Firebase App Check, are you?

Use Firebase App Check to verify that the request for your callable function is coming from your app, not from any other client.

If you use Firebase App Check, Cloud Functions won't throw this error.

Check [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/cloud-functions) for more info.